# Error: Insufficient funds. Required 1096934302059488651232480448211091758313913168 and got: 9999999999999999999999999999999999

Tags: web3js

I am sending 1 eth from one account to another account. But I am unable to understand why the required balance is too big. I am receiving following error message:

```
Error: Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds. Required 1096934302059488651232480448211091758313913168 and got: 9999999999999999999999999999999999.
```

I am using following script to send transaction:

```
const Web3 = require("web3"); //version "^0.20"
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx') //version "^1.3.4"
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));


function sendBalance(address, amountInEth){
    var addressFrom= "0x00B2386D9...............7DE370BF5B1d4893";
    var privateKey = new Buffer('d549079....................2ae7de5', 'hex')

    const gasPriceHex = web3.toHex(10);

    var nonceval = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom);

    var fTx = {
        nonce: nonceval,
        gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
        gasLimit: web3.toHex(210000),
        from: addressFrom,
        to: address,
        value: web3.toWei(amountInEth, 'ether')
    };

    var txx = new Tx(fTx);
    txx.sign(privateKey);

    var sTx =txx.serialize();
    console.log("Current Balance:",web3.eth.getBalance(addressFrom).toString());
    console.log("Transaction:",fTx)
    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + sTx.toString('hex'), (err, hash) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err); return; }

        // Log the tx, you can explore status manually with eth.getTransaction()
        console.log('Tx Hash: ' + hash);
    });
}


// usage
sendBalance("0x004ec........................9513386F32E",1)
```

The output and error I receive with this script is as follows:

```
Current Balance: 9.999999999999999999999999999999999e+33
Transaction: { nonce: 0,
  gasPrice: '0xa',
  gasLimit: '0x33450',
  from: '0x00B2386........................B1d4893',
  to: '0x004ec07..........................386F32E',
  value: '1000000000000000000' }
Error: Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not have enough funds. Required 1096934302059488651232480448211091758313913168 and got: 9999999999999999999999999999999999.
```

Note: Address and private keys have been modified to include minimal and relevant content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `value` was expected to be a hex value, but I was sending integer. Correction in script is in `var fTx`:

```
value: web3.toHex(web3.toWei(amountInEth, 'ether'))
```